# Cannot build with static link

Tags: go, build, static, linker, ld

I'm trying to build a go program with static link. I want to run this on a different system, with different version of glibc, without all the dependencies etc ...

So i looked up and found that you can pass arguments to the gcc compiler and tell him to statically link the dependencies. But i'm facing issue with "undefined_reference"

Here's the command i'm using : `go build --ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' src/main/command/main.go`

And the result :

```
# command-line-arguments
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running g++ failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-376220047/000023.o: in function `_cgo_26061493d47f_C2func_getaddrinfo':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:58: warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.a(libtesseract_la-baseapi.o): in function `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::ProcessPagesInternal(char const*, char const*, int, tesseract::TessResultRenderer*)':
(.text+0x7356): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x7378): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x7387): undefined reference to `curl_easy_strerror'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x73b6): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x7700): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x771e): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x773e): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x775e): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x7770): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x777f): undefined reference to `curl_easy_strerror'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x7b16): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.a(libtesseract_la-par_control.o): in function `tesseract::Tesseract::PrerecAllWordsPar(std::vector<tesseract::WordData, std::allocator<tesseract::WordData> > const&) [clone ._omp_fn.0]':
(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.a(libtesseract_la-par_control.o): in function `tesseract::Tesseract::PrerecAllWordsPar(std::vector<tesseract::WordData, std::allocator<tesseract::WordData> > const&)':
(.text+0x3eb): undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.a(libtesseract_ccutil_la-tessdatamanager.o): in function `tesseract::TessdataManager::LoadArchiveFile(char const*)':
(.text+0x406): undefined reference to `archive_read_new'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x416): undefined reference to `archive_read_support_filter_all'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x41e): undefined reference to `archive_read_support_format_all'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x42e): undefined reference to `archive_read_open_filename'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x44e): undefined reference to `archive_entry_pathname'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x45e): undefined reference to `archive_read_next_header'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x470): undefined reference to `archive_read_free'

...
```

The output is way bigger than that, it's just the start, but other errors are the same with different libraries.

i tried telling `ld` to find curl (for example) with the flag `-lcurl`, it works, but the problem is the same for many other libraries.

If you want to know the depedencies i use, here's the output of `ldd main` (the binary compiled dynamically) :

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe273ed000)
    liblept.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblept.so.5 (0x00007f70737d2000)
    libtesseract.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.so.5 (0x00007f707345e000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f707343c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f707326f000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f707312b000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7073111000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7072f4a000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f7072f10000)
    libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 (0x00007f7072e8c000)
    libgif.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgif.so.7 (0x00007f7072e81000)
    libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f7072dfb000)
    libwebpmux.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebpmux.so.3 (0x00007f7072def000)
    libwebp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 (0x00007f7072d84000)
    libopenjp2.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so.7 (0x00007f7072d27000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f7072d0a000)
    libarchive.so.13 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarchive.so.13 (0x00007f7072c42000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f7072ba7000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f7072b67000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7073a90000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f7072a8a000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f7072a62000)
    libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007f7072854000)
    libdeflate.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdeflate.so.0 (0x00007f7072838000)
    libnettle.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8 (0x00007f70727f0000)
    libacl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f70727e3000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f70727c0000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f70727ad000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f70725ff000)
    libnghttp2.so.14 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x00007f70725d2000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f70725b1000)
    librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x00007f7072590000)
    libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007f707255b000)
    libpsl.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5 (0x00007f7072547000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f70724b4000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f70721c0000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f707216d000)
    libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f7072115000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f7072104000)
    libbrotlidec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x00007f70720f6000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f70720f0000)
    libicuuc.so.67 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.67 (0x00007f7071f07000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f7071d83000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f7071b83000)
    libhogweed.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.6 (0x00007f7071b3a000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f7071ab9000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f7071999000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f70718bd000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f707188d000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f7071887000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f7071878000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f707185e000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f7071841000)
    libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x00007f707181c000)
    libicudata.so.67 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.67 (0x00007f706fd03000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f706fbcf000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f706fbb9000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f706fb93000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f706fb8a000)
    libffi.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 (0x00007f706fb7e000)
```

My questions are :

- Why ld cannot find curl and other libraries by itself ?
- How to know everything i need to install ?
- Even if i install every lib it needs, will it work ?

Comment: Check and see if you have all of the needed `lib*.a` files on your system. Typically, default packages only install the dynamic `lib*.so*` versions. Sometimes you need to install the extra static versions of packages to be able to statically link a binary.

Answer (score 0):

Add required libraries to the linker flags: `-static -lcurl -lssh2 -lssl -lcrypto -lz`. Also you probably need to install `-dev` versions of the libraries: `apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssh-dev zlib1g-dev`. It will install `lib*.a` files which are needed for static linking.